# Firedac, Oracle, Blob

Tags: oracle, blob, firedac

How can i get Clob Data out of and into my Oracle Database via Stored Procedure using Firedac.

The stored procedures are defined like this:

```
  PROCEDURE Get_Info_CLOB ( p_ID    IN  VARCHAR2,
                                p_INFO  OUT CLOB
                              );


  PROCEDURE Set_Info_CLOB (   p_ID    IN  VARCHAR2,
                                p_INFO  OUT CLOB
                            );
```

To read out the Blob works with the following

```
FDStP_BlattGetInfoClob->Prepare();
FDStP_BlattGetInfoClob->ParamByName(_T("P_ID"))->AsString   = rCBlobInfo.Id;

FDStP_BlattGetInfoClob->ExecProc();

rCBlobInfo.Info = FDStP_BlattGetInfoClob->ParamByName(_T("P_INFO"))->AsBlob;

FDStP_BlattGetInfoClob->Close();
```

but i want to do it with Streams like it was in the past, for example

```
Clob_Stream = SP_DsBlattInfoClob->ParamByName("P_INFO")->CreateBlobStream( 0, bmRead );
Clob_Stream = SP_DsBlattInfoClob->ParamByName("P_INFO")->CreateBlobStream( 0, bmWrite );
```

So i have some Problems.....
Both Stored Procedures are defined with "OUT" at the CLOB, so i think i will get a reference from Oracle to the BLOB Value. The target will be not to change anything inside the database.

The CreateBlobStream is only available with FieldByName, not with ParamByName.

I am not able to get in or out any data with Streams.
I tried already the following, like Embarcadero write in the description.

```
TMemoryStream* pStream = new TMemoryStream;
FDStP_BlattGetInfoClob->ParamByName(_T("P_INFO"))->AsStream = pStream;
```

Somebody has any Idea.
Thanks in advance....